# Mac won’t connect to internet

Tags: macos, mac, network, internet, ethernet

I have an interesting problem and I believe I may be halfway to understanding it but don’t know how to fix it. My home network has two routers. One is the main one and is in a cabinet so I do not have wifi enabled as the cabinet limits the range of the wifi. I have a second router placed elsewhere which runs my wifi. Currently Ethernet shows connected but no access To the internet. My guess is there is an issue with the iP address as the internet works on wifi with the Ethernet cable disconnected and slowly with it connected. With wifi off the Ethernet still doesn’t connect to internet even though shows green. I guess there is a conflict and would appreciate some advice. Thanks in advance

Comment: There's so many details missing like how this entire network is configured.  As written, this doesn't seem to be an Apple related question/issue.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: make sure to do a terminal "ping" and a terminal "traceroute" if its macOS specific then its likely in your "grep wifi /var/log/system.log" file and related to some installed software or conflict with a program that is connecting to the internet using the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

Apple covers the basics in troubleshooting internet connections.

- Solve internet connection problems on Mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/solve-internet-connection-problems-on-mac-mh11395/mac

This is a nice resource since it is specific to several versions of macOS and if it’s too technical, you can refine your problem by working through it and asking a follow on question with details of where you got stuck or what sort of information doesn’t make sense.

Here’s the how to connect which also might help: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201735